# Laravel queue:work not behaving same as queue:listen

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-queue

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class DynamicEmailChannel extends MailChannel
{
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $service = $notification->service;
        $customConfig = [];
        $from = [];
        if ($service->sender_email && $service->sender_password) {
            $customConfig = [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
                'port' => 587,
                'encryption' => 'tls',
                'username' => $service->sender_email,
                'password' => $service->sender_password,
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ];
            $from = [
                'address' => $service->sender_email,
                'name' => $service->title
            ];
        } else {
            $customConfig = [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
                'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ];
            $from = [
                'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
                'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example')
            ];
        }
        Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp', $customConfig);
        Config::set('mail.from', $from);
        app()->forgetInstance('mail.manager');
        parent::send($notifiable, $notification);
    }
}
```

this program works when run through `php artisan queue:listen` but the `app()->forgetInstance('mail.manager');` runs only once when run through `php artisan queue:work`. How do i make it behave as with `queue:listen`?

I am trying to send mail notifications through credentials saved in database.

If i am not wrong, if i delete the 'mail.manager' serviceInstance, it will create new one when called with latest config. it works the same way for `queue:listen` but not for `queue:work`. what am i missing, or not understanding here.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging replacing `app()->forgetInstance('mail.manager');` with `Mail::purge('smtp');` solved the issue.